# IOS AFNetworking 2.0 SSL client authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, ssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

How to implement client `SSL` authentication (with `client private key` and `client certificate`, it is the same as have one *.p12 or *.pfx key) using `AFNetworking` 2.0?

So. mutual authentication with client and server.

Comment: May be anyone know answer using only one *.p12 file (which contain both private key and certificate) for client?

Comment: anyone?  same question.

Comment: It is exactly possible to do, but I do not know how. If you find answer you may to write it here.

Comment: May be this answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137220/afnetworking-setauthenticationchallengeblock